# Get each image natural height with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have to read each images' natural height and I should make calculations. However, I have some problem with read to natural height.

```
$('div.imgkirp img').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).naturalHeight);
});
```

It gets: (images number) undefined in console log. How can I read each of the images' natural height?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = $(this).attr("src");
alert('width: ' + image.naturalWidth + ' and height: ' + image.naturalHeight);
```

This approach doesn't work in [Internet Explorer 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) and below versions, because it doesn't support 'naturalWidth' and 'naturalHeight' properties. To achieve the same, use this code:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = $(this).attr("src");
image.onload = function() {
  console.log('height: ' + this.height);
};
```

Comment: This just doesn't work.  I've tried in Chrome and I can see that the source is correct; I set it to the new Image's src property and naturalHeight/naturalWidth 'undefined'.

Answer (score 33):

Try to use property `naturalHeight` of the image, using the `prop` method of jQuery:

```
$('div.imgkirp img').each(function(){

   console.log($(this).prop('naturalHeight'));
});
```

Comment: Tried this as well and it didn't work for me.  Returns 'undefined'.

Comment: @ArtlyticalMedia you should use `load`. Because if the image is not loaded, may be returned "undefined".